# How to get sources from parent project as dependency

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I want to do something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':projectA', classifier: 'sources')
}
```

But I couldn't find such functionallity, I've searched in the documentation but there was nothing besides specifying the classifier on real dependencies.

So it there a way on adding the sources from an parent project inside a Gradle multimodules project as dependency?

Comment: What is the use case of having 'sources as dependency'? Usually you depend on compiled classes.

Comment: @MartinLinha the gwt compile needs the sources on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that there is a feature from Gradle for that, but there is a workaround:

1. Add an `packageSources` to the project which should provide sources

   ```
   // projectA/build.gradle   

   project.task("packageSources", type: Jar) {
       classifier = 'sources'
       from { project.sourceSets.main.allSource }
   }
   ```
2. Depend the task on `compileJava` where you need the sources

   ```
   // projectB/build.gradle

   compileJava.dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':projectA:packageSources')
   ```
3. Add the source as dependency

   ```
   // projectB/build.gradle

   dependencies {
       compile files(tasks.getByPath(':projectA:packageSources').archivePath)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

projectA/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    sources 
}
dependencies {
    sources sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

projectB/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':projectA', configuration: 'sources')
}
```

See [DependencyHandler.project(Map)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#project%28java.util.Map%29)

Comment: This is probably the better solution, the downside is that Intellij IDEA ignores that property.

Comment: @jmattheis Can use gradle idea task from idea plugin to refresh .iml files ;) IntelliJ gradle support was never perfect